# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type Selector

Tags: ios, null, swift3, selector

In converting from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, I receive the error above for the following line of code:

```
var contactButton: UIBarButtonItem {return self.CustomRightItem("icon-nav-nls-contact", target: self, action: nil)}
```

The problem is on the `nil` action. I've tried using and empty selector: `#selector()` and ```#selector(nil) both to no avail.

How can I handle a nil action in Swift 3?

Comment: CustomRightItem looks like it is a custom instance method of yours that creates a UIBarButtonItem. Perhaps you need to rewrite your function to take a `Selector?` (optional selector) rather than a selector? Or, as you show in your own answer, pass in an actual selector.

Comment: It looks like the Swift initializers for UIBarButtonItem take an optional selector, so modifying your function to take a `Selector?` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly placeholder code for a later action, so use a placeholder function where the code will eventually go and then call that selector as required with: `#selector(functionName(_:))`

Your full code will look like this:

```
var contactButton: UIBarButtonItem {return self.CustomRightItem("icon-nav-nls-contact", target: self, action: #selector(contactAction(_:)))}

func contactAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    return
}
```